# Wiping hard drive but need to keep windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive

I just recently got into linux, and it's great. However, I got a little ahead of myself and installed another OS just for fun. I regret that. Then somehow my sound is not working on anything but Lubuntu (the OS I regret). I'm trying to figure out how I could wipe my hard drive, but still "keep" my installation of Windows (not buy a new product key). I want all my Linux stuff gone.

Comment: If it was Windows 10, you don't need to worry about product keys. Microsoft's servers keep track of which systems have a license. You could wipe the PC and reinstall Windows clean and it would automatically activate.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows 10 was running (you seem to say it was running), then you can delete all on your disk and reinstall Windows from the ISO file on the Media Creation Link.  Then Windows 10 will activate from the Microsoft Licensing Server.  This is by design and permits users to change / upgrade disks in their computers.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM | tail -c 32 | xargs -0 echo
```

from Linux will print out your Windows license key - write it down. Then [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) the Windows iso from Microsoft and reinstall it. I believe Windows wants to take over the whole drive anyway.

If by some chance it doesn't just use cfdisk from Linux when you are ready to reinstall and delete *all* partitions and reboot.

If you want to keep your existing Windows installation you'll need to use Windows to reinstall the MBR (duckduckgo will show you how) and use a partition editor from within Windows to delete the Linux partitions.